# In QGIS change DEM elevations values from positive to negative

Tags: qgis, dem, convert, elevation, bathymetry

I have a DEM that currently has positive elevation values for bathymetry and negative values for those above sea level. How can I convert these cell values to negative for bathymetry and positive for topography.

Comment: Use the raster calculator with an expression such as: `raster_name@1*-1` where `raster_name` is the name of your raster layer. This should result in an output raster with positive and negative values reversed.

Comment: You should post this as an answer

Comment: That was so easy,  thank you Ben.

Answer (score -2):

You can do it easily using CIVIL 3D

https://knowledge.autodesk.com/support/civil-3d/troubleshooting/caas/sfdcarticles/sfdcarticles/Civil-3D-Convert-positive-elevations-to-negative-elevations.html